# Rails 6 - Action Cable Issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, actioncable

I'm a bit new to Ruby and I'm building a pretty simple Rails App that allows a chat type of feature using Action Cable. The tutorial I'm following isn't using rails 6 so it's a bit different when I'm building it, but it seems everything is working at this point other than the below jQuery to start an Action Cable connection. I'm getting a console error that states "Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined" on the cable.js file. This is the first time ever using Action Cable and rails so any help is much appreciated.

Here's a link to my git repo: https://github.com/scottlandes1217/Hubbubb

cable.js

```
// Action Cable provides the framework to deal with WebSockets in Rails.
// You can generate new channels where WebSocket features live using the `rails generate channel` command.
//
//= require action_cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./channels

(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

}).call(this);
```

forum_channel.js

```
$(function() {
  $('[data-channel-subscribe="forum"]').each(function(index, element) {
    var $element = $(element),
        forum_id = $element.data('forum-id')
        messageTemplate = $('[data-role="message-template"]');

    $element.animate({ scrollTop: $element.prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000)

    App.cable.subscriptions.create(
      {
        channel: "ForumChannel",
        forum: forum_id
      },
      {
        received: function(data) {
          var content = messageTemplate.children().clone(true, true);
          content.find('[data-role="user-avatar"]').attr('src', data.user_avatar_url);
          content.find('[data-role="message-text"]').text(data.message);
          content.find('[data-role="message-date"]').text(data.updated_at);
          $element.append(content);
          $element.animate({ scrollTop: $element.prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
        }
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: btw - this is the tutorial I'm following if that helps at all https://iridakos.com/programming/2019/04/04/creating-chat-application-rails-websockets

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the authors [Github repo](https://github.com/iridakos/rails-chat-tutorial/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts)?
I'm no expert in jQuery but it seems that you are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an incomplete answer:

I am also having issues still, as all the tutorials are for Rails 5.x, and the **cable.js** file is from the rails 5 era. rails 6 comes with a **app/javascripts/consumer.js** file, and you should delete or move all of **app/assets/javascripts**.

I believe we should not need to include jQuery. This has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with Action cable quite a bit, I wasn't able to find an easy solution. I went ahead and just downgraded to rails 5 and everything seems to be working great. I know that's not really an answer, but at least I was able to finish the project.